# How to get rid of folder inside eclipse Referenced Libraries

Tags: java, eclipse

I have one project in eclipse that has an extraneous folder in the list of referenced libraries that I can't get rid of, and is causing wrong libraries to be used.

[image: Project folder]

xtralibs is the folder where I keep all extra java libraries.  But it shouldn't be part of the referenced library list.  No idea why it is there.  And I can't delete it. It is only a problem on this one project.

Delete is grayed out, that folder does not show anywhere in the Java Build Path, tried cleaning the project, running Eclipse with -clean, still there. I also did a grep on both the project folder and my eclipse program folder and can't find a reference anywhere.

Per request, below is a screenshot showing that the folder is NOT in the build path.
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: go to java build path ->libraries -> remove them

Comment: @KumarAbhinav Please post answers as answers, not comments.

Comment: As I stated, the folder does not show up anywhere under Java Build Path.  That's why I am asking for help.

Comment: @FredAndrews It is actually hard to believe,so you should paste the screenshot of eclipse here.

Comment: did you check the ".classpath" file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `.classpath` file from your project and re-adding your libraries.

Comment: Although there was nothing in the .classpath file that appeared to have anything to do with adding a folder, deleting the file and re-adding the libraries did the trick.  Great!